# Create Windows 8.1 USB Boot Disk to Boot in OSX Maverick

Tags: usb, boot, windows-8.1, osx-mavericks

After I installed Mac OSX Maverick 10.9 to my Mac Computer. I have a problem with installing Microsoft Windows 8.1 into my Mac my using Bootcamp.

I try some third party software such as Win USB Boot Maker and Rufus. These softwares can make USB Boot disk for non Mac computer however they cannot make it work with Mac.

Does anyone know how to create a working Windows 8.1 USB Boot Disk to work with Mac computer which run OSX Maverick?

Thank You!

Pengan

Comment: This is not a question for [so]. Try asking on [su]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll try to post on it.

Comment: You need Windows to start with, but this tool has worked for me in the past: Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool (http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)

Comment: @Preston, It's not working with this tool too. It does work in Non Mac Computer however it's not working with Mac

Comment: Have you seen this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj945423.aspx